# Application windows randomly blinking (see video)

Tags: 12.04, unity, video, hybrid-graphics

Applications redraw frantically (blink white) for a couple minutes and then it stops.
I made a [video showing the issue](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fQksvkLKPxE). It is very weird behaviour.

**What is even strange** (or a clue?) is that:

- if I have a system menu open (mouse right click menu) then there is no redraw whatsoever
- also if I have the unity dash opened then the windows redraw underneath it!

It stops after a couple minutes (when the notebook heats up?)

**It happens** always after boot and after resume from a longer suspend period.

Everything blinks except the unity side launcher, top status bar and unity dash.

I am running:

- 12.04 fully updated.
- standard base video driver. Tried the flgx but got stuck in 2D mode (the issue did not happen there). Logged in gnome and it didn't happen either.
- Dell Inspiron with hybrid video (Intel + Radeon HD 6400M)

***Any ideas what it is or how to find a solution?***

Comment: Is it the same as running `setsid unity` in a terminal, then it's basically Unity that crashes. If you don't get a bug report, you have ether turned it of for Unity or for everything. You should turn it back on and go trough the bug report.

Comment: I always send bug reports.. Don't recall having turned it off.. How do I turn it on?

Comment: I did run `setsid unity` on the terminal and actually the redraw I got was the opposite of the issue I am facing.. The setsid caused all unity related windows to redraw while in my case all windows redraw except the unity related (launcher, top bar and dash). Also is very very weird because after 3-4 minutes it just stops.

Answer (score 1):

I would login as with the Gnome interface for a while to see if it is Unity that is causing the issue.

It sounds like a video driver issue but it could also be a video memory issue. To rule those out if you run a custom video driver I would revert to the base driver.

If you still get issues with a base video driver and Gnome I would very likely assume its hardware.

Comment: Thanks. I will Try gnome. I am using the standard base video driver.

Comment: it seems to happen in unity-3d only... very weird. I edited the question to add more info and improve the description.

Comment: @lpanebr good, its narrowed down but cant help you re unity as I dont use it as its just too annoying. Might be ok for a tablet but for a desktop and prductivity Gnome is my prefered choice

Comment: I do like Unity, but that's not really the point here.